# How to handle ManytoMany relationship between two model and design rest calls around them in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have been struggling from past one week for this issue i have been facing. So here's the Problem statement: I have a table TestSuite that has 'id' as its primary key(autogenerated) and has some other fields. I have another table TestCase that has 'id' as its primary key(autogenerated) and has some other fields. A person can make a post call to the TestCase api to create a testCase. But When a person makes a post call to create a new TestSuite they have to provide an array of TestCase id meaning those testcases are part of this testsuite. Before persisting the testsuite i need to make sure if there are testcases present in the database with the testcase id they provide and if so i have to create a record in testsuite table and make mapping entries of newly created testsuite-id and list of test case-ids in testsuite_testcase table.

This is what i have done so far:

**TestCase model class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="test_case")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class TestCase {      
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
   private Long id;

   @Column(name = "testcaseid")
   private String testCaseId;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;

   @Column(name = "version")
   private String version;

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy="testcases")
   private Set<TestSuite> testsuites; 

   public TestCase() {
      super();
   }

   public TestCase(String testCaseId, String name, String version) {
          super();
          this.testCaseId = testCaseId;
          this.name = name;
          this.version = version;
   }
   //getters and setters for the fields
}
```

**TestSuite Model Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="test_suite")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class TestSuite {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="testsuiteid",nullable=false)
    private String testSuiteId;

    @Column(name="name", nullable=false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name="version", nullable=false)
    private String version="1.0";

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "test_suite_test_case", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "testsuite_id",referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "testcase_id",referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<TestCase> testcases;

    public TestSuite() {

    }
    public TestSuite(String testSuiteId, String name, String version,Set<TestCase> testcases){
        super();
        this.testSuiteId = testSuiteId;
        this.name = name;
        this.version = version;
        this.testcases=testcases;
    }
    //getters and setter for the feilds
}
```

**TestCase Repository class**

```
@Repository
public interface TestCaseRepository extends JpaRepository<TestCase, Long> {

}
```

**TestSuite Repository class**

```
@Repository
public interface TestSuiteRepository extends JpaRepository<TestSuite, Long>{
    TestSuite findByTestSuiteId(String testSuiteId);
}
```

**TestSuite Service Class**

```
@Service
public class TestSuiteService {

    @Autowired
    TestSuiteRepository testSuiteRepository;

    @Autowired
    TestCaseRepository testCaseRepository;


    public TestSuite createTestSuite(TestSuite testSuite) {
        TestSuite existingTestSuite = testSuiteRepository.findByTestSuiteId(testSuite.getTestSuiteId());
        boolean tcNotPresent=false;

        if(existingTestSuite!=null) {
            throw new ApiException(ErrorType.TESTSUITE_ALREADY_EXISTS);
        } else {

            Set<TestCase> testcases=testSuite.getTestcases();
            for(TestCase testCase: testcases) {

                if(testCaseRepository.findById(testCase.getId())==null) {
                    tcNotPresent=true;
                }
            }

            if(!tcNotPresent) {
    return testSuiteRepository.save(testSuite);
            }else {
                throw new ApiException(ErrorType.TESTCASE_NOT_FOUND);
            }
        }
    }

    public void deleteTestSuite(Long id) {
        TestSuite existingTestSuite=testSuiteRepository.findById(id).get();
        testSuiteRepository.delete(existingTestSuite);
    }
}
```

**Test Suite Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/")
public class TestSuiteController {

    @Autowired
    TestSuiteService testSuiteService;

    //this api is to POST a new testSuite record in the testsuites table
    @RequestMapping(value="testsuites",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @ResponseBody
    public TestSuite createTestSuite(@RequestBody TestSuite testSuite) {
        return testSuiteDAO.createTestSuite(testSuite);
    }

    //This api is to DELETE a single record from testsuites table based on testSuiteId
    @RequestMapping(value="testsuites/{id}",method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    public void deleteTestSuite(@PathVariable Long id) {
        testSuiteDAO.deleteTestSuite(id);
    }
}
```

Not including the Testcase controller and Testcase Service classes as they are generic post api structure for a spring boot application.
When I run the above code with a post request from postman with the following request body:

```
{   
   "testSuiteId": "testsuite_1",
    "name": "testsuite_1",
    "version": "1.0",
    "testcases":[
      {
        "id": 2,
        "testCaseId": "testcase_1",
        "name": "testcase_1",
        "version": "1.0"
    },
        {
        "id": 4,
        "testCaseId": "testcase_4",
        "name": "testcase_4",
        "version": "1.0"
    }]

}
```

I am getting this error:

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.testreport.gopherUIBackend.model.TestCase
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:807) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:774) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:80) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:467) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:392) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:500) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:432) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:395) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:445) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:783) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:768) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:305) ~[spring-orm-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy96.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:490) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:629) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:593) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.9.RELEASE.jar:2.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy103.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.testreport.gopherUIBackend.dao.TestSuiteDAO.createTestSuite(TestSuiteDAO.java:59) ~[classes/:na]
at com.testreport.gopherUIBackend.controller.TestSuiteController.createTestSuite(TestSuiteController.java:46) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar:8.5.32]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

I have tried all possible ways but not knowing what i am doing wrong. Please suggest some ideas. Also I was wondering Do i need to send the entire testcase in the request body of testSuite POST call or can i just send an array of testcase ('id')?

Comment: what is TestSuiteDAO here?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. its actually TestSuiteService. edited the post with the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove @GeneratedValue from both TestCase entity. You are sending the test cases with specific ids, but you configured hibernate to generate their values => they will be detached.

UPDATE

If you want to keep generated value, you will not be able to create new TestCases when you create a TestSuite. The most you can do is to update the values and fail with exception if they fail.

```
public TestSuite createTestSuite(TestSuite testSuite) {
    Set<TestCase> testCases = testSuite.getTestcases().stream()
        .map(this::getPersistedTestCase)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    //set relationship to update the relationship table
    testSuite.setTestcases(testCases);
    testSuiteRepository.save(testSuite);
}

private TestCase getPersistedTestCase(TestCase testCase) {
    Optional<TestCase> persistedTestCase = testCaseRepository.findById(testCase.getId());
    if (persistedTestCase.isPresent()) {
        return persistedTestCase.get();
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Missing Test Case with id : " + testCase.getId());
}
```

You must remove cascade = CascadeType.ALL from @ManyToMany relationship, it will indicate no cascade, just update the relationship table.

It is against the generated value concept to have both generated and not-generated ids. A workaround would be that when you create a new testcase, to take the next generated value in the sequence and save the entity with it. You will need to remove @GeneratedValue annotation and make sure that you don't have concurrency problems.

Comment: I need to have @GeneratedValue in my Test Case and Test Suite because i can create a test case by making a separate api call to the testCase Controller. Something like this:
    
    POST(/api/testcases)
    Request Body: {
    "testCaseId": "TestCase_1",
    "name": "Testcase_1",
    "version": "1.0"
    }
Note: I should be able to create a test case without creating a test suite(for which i need to have @GeneratedValue). But For creating a test suite i need to specify which all testcases should be part of it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The above logic worked. I also removed the cascade = CascadeType.ALL. After doing this i was getting another exception while doing a POST request for Test Suite: "Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException".
I resolved this issue by adding  "@JsonBackReference" annotation in my Test case Model Class.

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="testcases", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
      private Set<TestSuite> testsuites;
Now everything is working as expected. Thanks.